# How to tail multiple files in fluentd

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logging, fluentd

I have setup fluentd logger and I am able to monitor a file by using fluentd `tail input` plugin. All the data is received by fluentd is later published to `elasticsearch` cluster. Below is the configuration file for fluentd:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /home/user/Documents/log_data.json
  format json
  tag myfile
</source>

<match *myfile*>
  @type elasticsearch
  hosts 192.168.48.118:9200
  user <username>
  password <password>
  index_name fluentd
  type_name fluentd
</match>
```

As you can see I am monitoring `log_data.json` file by using `tail`. I also have a file in the same directory `log_user.json`, I want to monitor it also and publish it logs to `elasticsearch`. To do this, I thought of creating another `<source>` & `<match>` with different tag but it started showing errors.

How can I monitor multiple files in `fluentd` and publish them to `elasticsearch`. I see when we start `fluentd` its worker is started. Is it possible to start multiple worker so that each one of them is monitoring different files, or any other way of doing it. Can anyone point me to some good links/tutorials.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use multiple source+match tags.

Label can help you to bind them.

Here an example:

```
<source>     
  @label @mainstream
  @type tail /home/user/Documents/log_data.json
  format json
  tag myfile
</source>


<label @mainstream>
  <match **>
    @type copy

    <store>
      @type               elasticsearch
      host                elasticsearch
      port                9200
      logstash_format     true
      logstash_prefix     fluentd
      logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
      include_tag_key     true
      type_name           access_log
      tag_key             @log_name
      <buffer>
        flush_mode            interval
        flush_interval        1s
        retry_type            exponential_backoff
        flush_thread_count    2
        retry_forever         true
        retry_max_interval    30
        chunk_limit_size      2M
        queue_limit_length    8
        overflow_action       block
      </buffer>
    </store>

  </match>
</label>
```

Comment: Can you also explain your example. Where is the path to the files you are giving in your example.?

Comment: The aim of the answer was to show the use of label. Anyway I modified the answer in the source section where I wrote the path to the file.

Comment: The question asked for multiple files, but the example only shows one.